# Templates: Instantiate an object with a member of class type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've a factory method which creates Mesh objects. A mesh object has a Vertex class member which can be of various flavor.

```
template<class T>
    NewMesh* createMesh(T)
    {
        mesh_data* md = new mesh_data;
        T* vd = new T;
        md->vdata = vd;
        NewMesh* mptr = new NewMesh(generateUid());
        mptr->setData(md);

        return mptr;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is something like this, which should create a Mesh object with a vertex_data_P3_N3 class member for vdata.

```
Mesh* polym = meshFactory.createMesh(vertex_data_P3_N3);
```

Rather obviously, this doesn't work and throws a compile time error.

This works, but is ugly for obvious reason (declare a variabel that is not used):

```
vertex_data_P3_N3 vd;
Mesh* polym = meshFactory.createMesh(vd);
```

What's a better way to pass the class type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function parameter of `createMesh` is unused, which is a strong indication of it being redundant.

```
template<class T>
    NewMesh* createMesh() { ...


Mesh* polym = meshFactory.createMesh<vertex_data_P3_N3>();
```